# nodejs : get url in OutgoingMessage

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, url, meteor

My goal is to intercept every outgoing message from my server in a meteor project and add some stuff (meta datas and additional contents)

I have this simple code :

```
var http = Npm.require( 'http' ),
    originalWrite = http.OutgoingMessage.prototype.write;

http.OutgoingMessage.prototype.write = function ( chunk, encoding ) {
    console.log( this, arguments );
    chunk = chunk.replace( 'some code', 'elements to add' );
    originalWrite.call( this, chunk, encoding );
}
```

It works but I cannot find the url of the current call. This is a problem because I need to add different elements according to the called url.

(nota : I have a condition to make sure the request is an html file)

Answer (score 1):

The full URL isn't directly available but host and path are through the request header `Host` and a property `path` on the `OutgoingMessage` object.

To obtain the full URL:

```
var url = this.getHeader('host') + this.path; //or this._headers.host;
```

--

```
var originalWrite = http.OutgoingMessage.prototype.write;

http.OutgoingMessage.prototype.write = function () {
  var url = this.getHeader('host') + this.path;
  //...
  return originalWrite.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

The reason `path` isn't available in the header is because the request path is part of the `Request-Line`. The `OutgoingMessage` implementation first establishes a TCP connection to the host and then issues a request on the path.

```
GET /path HTTP/1.1
Host: hostname
```

Comment: All three elements (`this.getHeader('host')`, `this.path`and `this._headers.host`) returned `undefined`. Could it be a problem with the version of node meteor use ? (0.10.33)